# Adding route on OpenVPN server side to connect VPN Clients to the internal LAN

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn, windows-server-2019

I am using a Windows Server 2019.

I have an OpenVPN Server listening a NIC with IP 192.16.2.10 (Subnet 255.255.255.0). Connected to the Fritz!Box Router. The router is configured to forward UDP port 1194 to the appropriate NIC.

The internal LAN has a different NIC with IP 192.168.16.205 (Subnet 255.255.255.0).

I can connect from extern to the OpenVPN Server and I get a successful connection.

But the Ping from the external VPN Client to another server in the local net (for example the DNS server 192.168.16.201) fail.

I sam stuck on the documentation
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO#ExpandingthescopeoftheVPNtoincludeadditionalmachinesoneithertheclientorserversubnet telling me that I have to do nothing, because I use `dev tap`

> Make sure that you've enabled IP and TUN/TAP forwarding on the OpenVPN
> server machine.
>
> Including multiple machines on the server side when using a bridged
> VPN (dev tap) One of the benefits of using ethernet bridging is that
> you get this for free without needing any additional configuration.

All firewalls (Windows firewalls) are turned off. All hints only point on the Firewall settings...

- I can't ping any server in my local net 192.168.16.x
- I can't reach any server in my local net 192.168.16.x with RDP.
- DNS doesn't work either. (DNS server at 192.168.16.201)

Any ideas?

Here my server.ovpn file:

```
#################################################
# OpenVPN 
#################################################
local 192.168.2.10
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap
topology subnet

#----------------------------------------------
#Zertifikate
#----------------------------------------------
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh.pem"
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\VPNServer-01.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\VPNServer-01.key"

#----------------------------------------------
#Server-Setup
#----------------------------------------------
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\ipp.txt"
client-to-client

#----------------------------------------------
#Client-Settings (inkl Special Dir) Files - OPTIONAL
#----------------------------------------------
#client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\ccd" 
push "route 192.168.16.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.16.201"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN vpn.xyz.loc"

#----------------------------------------------
#Defaults
#----------------------------------------------
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
allow-compression yes
cipher AES-256-GCM
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-CBC

#----------------------------------------------
# Logging
# ----------------------------------------------
status "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn-status.log"
log "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
# log-append "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
verb 3
```

PS: I use `dev tap` according to the following link, the second answer seams to match for my situation:

https://serverfault.com/questions/21157/should-i-use-tap-or-tun-for-openvpn

Comment: What does the client's IP config look like after connecting? Does it get a .16. IP and the route/dns/domain settings?

Comment: No, The OpenVPN tap device gets a 10.8.0.x IP 4. What do you mean with the route/dns/domain settings? What settings? Were should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dev tap` is a layer-2 vpn, which means you're extending the server's local `192.168.16.0` subnet across the tunnel (no ip routing)

Do not use `server [ip-pool]`. You need [server-bridge](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/) instead for TAP, as mentioned in the documentation. You also should not need `push "route"` unless you want to send client traffic for subnets other than .16 through the vpn

```sh
# bridge vpn to an adapter on server
# example of allowing client IPs .100 to .200
server-bridge 192.168.16.202 255.255.255.0 192.168.16.100 192.168.16.200
```

There are more steps involved with setting up bridging in the how-to, but it depends on your server configuration and preference

Comment: Correct that if my internal Lan NIC is 192.168.16.205, I need server-bridge 192.168.16.205... ?

Comment: I now receive an IP 192.168.16.64, but access into my net still doesn't work. Firewalls are disabled on all sides.

Comment: Thank you so far. I open a new Query. This first steps were successful but it is getting more complicate to discuss it here. The primary question is answered.