# OpenVPN Ethernet Bridging doesn't work, the access from client to internal network fails

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2019

Configuration:

- Server: Windows Server 2019 Standard
- Server internal network IP is 192.168.16.204
- DNS on 192.168.16.201
- Access to the Internet is donbe via 192.168.2.10 (Fritz!Box using Port forwarding)
- Client: Windows 10
- Firewalls are all off

OpenVPN Server can be successfully connected from the client. Client receives the IP 192.168.16.64 as expected.

Server is configured for (full server.ovpn file below)

```
local 192.168.2.10
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap
dev-node OpenVPN-TAP-Bridge
topology subnet
server-bridge 192.168.16.204 255.255.255.0 192.168.16.64 192.168.16.80
```

As described [here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/#notes-ethernet-bridging-on-windows) I bridged the internal network and the TAP adapter and set the IP address of the bridge to the internal server address 192.168.16.205. (see picture below).

But when I use a ping from the client (IP 192.168.16.64) to an internal IP on the network (192.168.16.170) than it doesn't work. Also no DNS works. Of course no RDP.

Any idea what to check and to look for? WireShark is available on the server. but I have no real experience with it.

Also I can see, that after enabling creating bridge, I have no longer access to the Domain network.

Here a picture from the configuration:
[image: Configuration of Bridge]

Full server.ovpn here:

```
#################################################
# OpenVPN 
#################################################

local 192.168.2.10
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap
dev-node OpenVPN-TAP-Bridge
topology subnet

#----------------------------------------------
# Certificates
#----------------------------------------------
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\dh.pem"
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\issued\\VPNServer-01.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\pki\\private\\VPNServer-01.key"

#----------------------------------------------
# Server-Setup
# https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/
# https://superuser.com/questions/1735151/adding-route-on-openvpn-server-side-to-connect-vpn-clients-to-the-internal-lan
#----------------------------------------------
# Allow IPs from 64 to 80 for bridging
server-bridge 192.168.16.204 255.255.255.0 192.168.16.64 192.168.16.80
client-to-client

#----------------------------------------------
# Client-Settings (inkl Special Dir) Files
#----------------------------------------------
# client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\ccd" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.16.201"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN vpn.abcd.loc"

#----------------------------------------------
#Defaults
#----------------------------------------------
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
allow-compression yes
cipher AES-256-GCM
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-CBC

#----------------------------------------------
# Logging
# ----------------------------------------------
status "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn-status.log"
log "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
# log-append "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\log\\openvpn.log"
verb 3
```

Comment: You probably want another adapter on the server for your internal subnet, since you can't really communicate over bridged adapters. Bridging just sends **everything** received on (example) `eth0` directly out `eth1` (so the server never sees it).

Comment: For troubleshooting - open wireshark on the server, select your bridged interface, and set the filter to `host 192.168.16.64`. Check whether the server sees traffic **from** the client AND whether the server sees traffic back **to** the client.